# Pointer arguments with compile-time ampersand checks

Tags: c++

Can I get the compiler to check that my function which expects a pointer argument has been called with `&someValidVariable` rather than `NULL`, some variable, or some literal address?

I'd like to use pointer arguments over reference arguments because those ampersands make, IMO, code easier to understand but I'm lazy to do non-NULL checks.

Can I get the best of both worlds?

Comment: This is unrelated to the c programming language, please check your tags before posting the question.

Comment: “easier to understand” is arguable. What’s not arguable is that it makes the code more brittle — as you’ve discovered.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that even when null-checked a pointer is not necessarily valid while a reference is?

Comment: @iharob The only thing C++ about the question is the allusion to not using reference arguments. Functions with pointer arguments are a common subset of C and C++, and for all I know, there could be a way to get a C compiler to check this too.

Comment: You can't determine how a value was created, only what it is.

Comment: @Pixelchemist You can't control everything. Not even with references. You can create references out of dereferenced invalid pointers, pass those around, and only have your program crash at the point where the invalid reference is accesses (possibly only for reading).

Comment: @PSkocik The problem you describe arises from using pointers in the first place. Generally avoiding pointers where possible and wrapping them in a sensibe way where not, is probably safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `nullptr` you can add an overload that takes a dummy [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) as argument.

But other than that it's not really possible, with the exception for arrays which you can do e.g.

```
template<std::size_t N>
void your_function(int (&array)[N]) { ... }
```

instead of letting it decay to a pointer.

Comment: The overload for `std::nullptr_t` will only match on calls that explicitly pass `nullptr`; they won't catch call with a pointer variable that happens to hold a null pointer (and it would indeed be naive to expect that such a situation could be could be caught by some compile-time mechanism at all).

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can declare an overload of the function that accepts a `std::nullptr_t`, and not define that function.   This will typically cause a linker error (as distinct from a compiler error).    (Although that won't stop the caller from doing something like `your_function((YourVariable *)nullptr)` - which will call your function with a NULL pointer).

Other than that (in any version of C++) it is not possible, apart from some special cases like passing a reference to an array (such a function will not be passed `NULL` or (in C++11) `nullptr`).   The reason is that a basic property of pointers is that they are passed by value, and the compiler permits that if the type (or permitted type conversions) is valid.   Once the value is passed, the only way to check is at run-time within the function.   The only exception is passing the value of an uninitialised pointer which, in itself, causes undefined behaviour (so anything can happen, and all bets are off).

But, really, the real solution to your problem is to pass references.  One of the purposes is providing a guarantee that they reference an actual object (dereferencing a `NULL` to create a reference gives undefined behaviour, as does using a dangling reference to an object that has been destroyed). So you really need to work to better understand what references are and how to use them properly, rather than trying to avoid using them.